# Different banner for different section

Tags: categories, pages, custom-header

I have different section like about us, portfolio, gallery. Client want to upload different  banner for different section that I have given on every page custom field. But problem is I want same banner image for About us section ( all inner pages). I search in many forum but I think no one have done this before.